# Serialization of Checkbox values into Boolean values

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I have some js that is trying to handle a checkbox value (assume not taken care of in "main.js")

```
var doctor = _$form.serializeFormToObject(); 
var mdoMipsCheckbox = $("input[name='MdoMips']:checked");
doctor.MdoMips = mdoMipsCheckbox.val();
```

the view looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MdoMips" value="@Model.Doctor.MdoMips" class="filled-in" id="doctor-mdomips" @(Model.Doctor.MdoMips ? "true" : "") />
```

And the model for both Dto and Entity have the property:

```
[Column("MDO_MIPS")]
[DisplayName("MDO MIPS")]
public bool MdoMips { get; set; }
```

My problem is that my serialized object looks like:

```
BirthDate:"25-Dec-1962"
FirstName:"Philip"
Id:"4"
LastName:"Fergus"
MdoMips:**"on"**
MdoOther:"rrr"
Title:"Mr"
```

which fails validation.

I'm not sure what is the best way to fix this so that I see "true" or "false" values on the serialized boolean property.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: change public bool MdoMips to public byte MdoMips

Comment: that's going to break my inline if statements  @(Model.NewDoctorPractice.InRacgpCpd  ? "checked" : ""

Comment: why do you need @(Model.NewDoctorPractice.InRacgpCpd ? "checked" ?

Comment: so when the edit modal dialog opens up is shows the correct value previously saved

Comment: I think it's not needed. just remove this and then try.

Comment: yes it worked! you just made the day for newbie javascripter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `public bool MdoMips` to `public byte MdoMips`.
2. Remove `@(Model.Doctor.MdoMips ? "true" : "")` from html, its not
   needed Angular does two way binding.

Comment: not using angular unfortunately...jquery - and the checked status does not get serialized as "1"...crazy

Answer (score 0):

What about using this :

```
doctor.MdoMips = mdoMipsCheckbox.is(":checked") ? "true" : "false";
```